# Is there a code level approach to triggers with JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

We have a moderate size Spring data / JPA application with around 100 tables.  We have been fairly strict about design leaving the RDBMS to do what it is good at; persistence and maintaining all program logic at the code level.  We now need to extend the application so that events can be triggered in a systematic way from RDBMS inserts and updates.  We could potentially achieve this with database triggers calling programmatic methods, however we would like to keep the trigger functionality at the application level if possible.  Is there a systematic approach to achieving this with JPA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Hibernate with spring-data-jpa you can easily register listeners to achieve application level triggers on inserts and updates. Check this [post](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html).

I am sure other ORM framework's also provide something similar.

Comment: Thank you - the post is helpful.  I am using Eclipselink and  MySQL, however I am thinking that Listeners function at a table (object) level.  Is that correct.  What if I have a more complex rule - say ... "Only execute code if table A is updated AND Table B is Updated"